# How do render outputs of async functions in React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I am trying to get an JSON output from the backend and displaying it using a async function but I'm getting am error saying -

```
TypeScript error in /src/views/Sent.tsx(41,9):
Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

    39 |       )}
    40 |       {rows &&
  > 41 |         rows.map((row))(
       |         ^
    42 |           <p>row.id</p>
    43 |       )}
    44 |     </>
```

My src/views/Sent.tsx file

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { sent } from '../utils/transactions';

export const Sent : FC = () =>  {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>('');
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setError('');
    try {
      const data = await sent();
      console.log(data);
      setRows(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        // handle errors thrown from frontend
        setError(err.message);
      } else {
        // handle errors thrown from backend
        setError(err);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!rows && !error && (
        <a className={classes.link} href="#" onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
          Click to make request to backend
        </a>
      )}
      {rows &&
        rows.map((row))(
          <p>row.id</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  link: {
    color: '#61dafb',
  },
}));
```

My /utils/transactions.ts file,

```
export const sent = async() => {

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const request = new Request('/sentList',{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })

  const response = await fetch(request);

  if (response.status === 500) {
    throw new Error('Internal server error');
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  if (response.status > 400 && response.status < 500) {
    if (data.detail) {
      throw data.detail;
    }
    throw data;
  }

  return data
};
```

I'm really new to TypeScript and React. Any help will be really appreciated.

Secondly is there any way for this to work without the request button? (Can the request to the backend be sent on the page loading without the need for the button)?

(Also this is my first question on Stack Overflow so forgive me for any mistakes.)

Comment: `rows.map((row))( <p>row.id</p> )}` is invalid syntax for mapping

Comment: Can you please tell the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things here :-

Initialize your `rows` state to be an empty array like so :-

`const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);`

Correct the `.map` in your JSX :-

```
{rows.map((row)=><p>{row.id}</p>)}
```

Also update the following to factor in `rows` length:-

```
 {!rows.length && !error && (
   <a className={classes.link} href="#" onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
        Click to make request to backend
   </a>
 )}
```

Comment: Adding <any> in this line works const [rows, setRows] = useState<any>([]); . I have submitted an edit request. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Wesaned Why use `any` when you can write `Row[]`? (Assuming you have defined the `Row` type, containing the id property etc)